# Equation Number Positioning in Align Environment

Tags: equations, align

How do I control the space between the equation number and the right margin in the `align` environment?

Comment: @Papiro It is not a duplicate.

Comment: do you want the position of the equation number changed only for the `align` environment, or for all numbered displays?

Comment: since you haven't said what the `\gls{...}` commands do (there is no example given, and i can't find any reference to that command in the *companion*), there's not enough information to give a meaningful answer to this question.  perhaps it should be closed.  regretfully downvoted.

Comment: No problems. GLS are glossaries commands, When I asked the question, I hadn't identified them as the source. I'll try and submit a minimal reproduceable example later today. Cheers.

Comment: @barbarabeeton I have posted a different question. http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134587/glossaries-in-align-environment

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A following example hacks into internals of `align` to add extra space that can be configured using `\alignnumbersep`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newdimen\alignnumbersep
\setlength{\alignnumbersep}{10mm}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\math@cr@@@align@measure}
     {\df@tag\fi\fi}
     {\df@tag\fi\fi\kern\alignnumbersep}
     {}{}
\patchcmd{\math@cr@@@align}
    {\make@display@tag}
    {\make@display@tag\kern\alignnumbersep}
    {}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{gather}
  \text{gather}
\end{gather}

\begin{align}
  a&=b & c&=d\\
  aa&=bb & cc&=dd
\end{align}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: It turns out that whilst the trigger for my question was an unrelated matter (see http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134587/glossaries-in-align-environment), this question as it stands and what you have answered is something that I have wanted to know regardless, so I thank you for your answer.