# Glossaries in Align Environment

Tags: amsmath, align, glossaries

Using glossaries commands in align environment seems to screw up the tag alignment.

How can I use `gls{...}` commands in align environments without the tag position being altered?

Consider the following code:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,glossaries}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}

\newacronym{E}{\ensuremath{E}}{Energy}
\makeglossaries

\begin{document}
    Standard gather environment
    \begin{gather}
        E = mc^2
    \end{gather}
    Glossaries Command in Align: 
    \begin{align}
        \gls{E} &= mc^2
    \end{align}
    Same align environment, with the `gls` command missing:
    \begin{align}
        E &= mc^2
    \end{align}
\end{document}
```

Which yields the following result, alignment differences should be clear:

[image: Output]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The explanation is already given in [egreg's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/134590/16967). Package `amsmath` processes the equations twice. First is measures the equation in order to know, whether it has to shift the equation number for wide equations. Then the equation is actually set.

`\gls{E}` changes its appearance. In the measuring step it is called the first time with the long form. Then in the second step, it generates the short form, confusing `amsmath` that had expected the long form.

The following example patches `\glsunset` that sets a flag, if the entry is set the first time. The measuring phase can be detected via switch `\ifmeasuring@`:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}

\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts,glossaries}
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}

\newacronym{E}{\ensuremath{E}}{Energy}

\makeglossaries

\makeatletter
\let\org@glsunset\glsunset
\renewcommand*{\glsunset}[1]{%
  \ifmeasuring@
  \else
    \org@glsunset{#1}%
  \fi
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
    Standard gather environment
    \begin{gather}
        E = mc^2
    \end{gather}
    Glossaries Command in Align:
    \begin{align}
        \text{\gls{E}} &= mc^2
    \end{align}
    Same align environment:
    \begin{align}
        \text{\gls{E}} &= mc^2
    \end{align}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Comment: I didn't know about `\ifmeasuring@`. I'll add a check for it in the next version of glossaries. Thanks, Heiko.

Comment: Thanks Heiko. Although in practice I wouldn't use the long form within equations (my presumption is that the 'first use', in reality, would come beforehand in a document), that is easy to fix and your answer is perfect in the case of this question. Cheers.

Answer (score 6):

The material in the `align` environment is processed twice, one for measuring it and the second one for actually typesetting it.

Since `\gls{E}` didn't appear earlier, in the first pass it is expanded to the long form and this is what LaTeX uses for deciding the column width; but in the second pass the acronym has already appeared (in a box that's discarded), so it's typeset in the short form.

It makes little sense to use `\gls` in an `align`, doesn't it?

Comment: Cheers. Why does it not make sense? What about a large book that needs to keep consistency in symbols and math terms, or that needs a glossaries table at the front listing all of the math terms and symbols used?

Comment: @ADP Do you really want that the formula reads "Energy (E)=mc^2"? I'd rule this as plainly wrong.

Comment: of course. short terms in the align environment. now that you explained the mechanism of how it works, I didn't know two passes were done. Using `\glsunset{...}` prior fixes the issue outlined in initial question.