# How to combine paragraphs of text with equations using \shortintertext and 'align'

Tags: equations, align, paragraphs, line-spacing, mathtools

I commented that I'm solving problems to make a book of basic math (or precalculus). 
In the environment or region of solving an exercise I want to combine paragraphs of text (using `\shortintertext`) with equations which I can align with respect to any sign of equality or inequality (`align` environment). I wish I could list some of these equations. And most importantly, I want to control the line spacing in this development environment. You can see that the following code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\begin{document}

\begin{align*}
\shortintertext{The equation is..}
4x &= 3x + 3&&(1)\\
\shortintertext{then by t2 and t7 theorems have..}
\left(3x+3\leq 4x <x+4\right) & &&(2)\\
\shortintertext{..respectively}
\end{align*}

\end{document}
```

will produce this document in DVI in which the numbering of formulas (or equations)  are not close to the right margin.   **I want these numbers (within the parenthesis) are located very close to the right margin.**
[image: screenshot 01 - line spacing with \begin{align}]

To control the line spacing I tried with commands like `\addtolength{\jot}{2em}`

```
\begingroup
\addtolength{\jot}{2em}
\begin{align*}
\shortintertext{The equation is..}\\[0.1em]
4x &= 3x + 3&&(1)\\
\shortintertext{then by t2 and t7 theorems have..}\\[0.1em]
\left(3x+3\leq 4x <x+4\right) & &&(2)\\
\shortintertext{..respectively}
\end{align*}
\endgroup
```

and becomes chaotic:
[image]

Can you solve or should I choose other environments?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not sure exactly what the question is. Do you just want the equation labels to be closer to the equations? If so, that does not at all seem related to the title. Please edit the question to clarify.

Comment: one problem with this is that the text "then by ..." is not *short*.  short implies that the text would fit in the "blank" area at the left of the equation lines around it.  you should use just `\intertext` in this case.

Comment: Sorry , I have some trouble passing the Spanish into English, but in my last edition I think I have clarified the question a little more.

Comment: In the last edition I wrote "I want those numbers (numbering of equations) in brackets appear close together in the right margin". And the second question is how can I control the line spacing in this paragraph that combines equations and text? Thanks for your answer barbara beeton, I'll try now.

Comment: Thanks Barbara, with `\intertext` have solved the problem of spacing of the lines in my development environment exercises. Now we just solve the problem with the numbers of equations, which should appear near the right margin, I hope someone understands this question to help me.

Comment: Why are you messing with `jot`, if you do not know what it does, don't mess with it. And no, it is not particularly clear what you mean by `numbers close together`. I also do not understand why you are starding the `align` with a comment, why is that not outside `align`. It might be a better idea if you took some more time to exactly explain what it is you are trying to do. LaTeX can do many things and there are many packages, perhaps there is a much better solution to what ever it is you are trying to do.

Comment: I don't understand why you have equation numbers with an align* environment – it is supposed to suppress equation numbering. You must have some other code that produces those numbers.

Comment: Question: Why are you using align* if you want to number equations? In case you are after equation numbering you should use align. Suggestion: As it looks you are manually entering 1 and 2,etc. If you want to persist with `align*`, you can use `\tag{1}` and `\tag{2}`, instead of writing (1) and (2).

Comment: @Umz Thanks Umz. Your advice is right now I think my problem is solved, `\tag` is a great solution my friend: D

Comment: @Bernard Sorry again, maybe not clearly explained my problem. In this screenshot you can see more clearly what I wanted http://i.stack.imgur.com/z34wc.jpg, is also in my latest edition of this post.

Comment: @dalif I used `jot` because I want the lines are farther apart, whether text or equations. I understand that it seems odd to try to align equations having intermediate texts, but only because later put equations consecutively within the paragraph for solving exercises in my book. I do not want to get another environment within the `align` environment. I also want to solve or simplify parallel inequalities (2 in each row of equation) where I will use the symbol `\wedge` (logical conjunction) which I will separate the inequalities and want to keep aligned with respect to the symbol...

Comment: You can use the solution from [Equation Number Positioning in Align Environment](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/134505/equation-number-positioning) with `\setlength{\alignnumbersep}{0mm}`.

Comment: @dalif ..But I want the time I want to place text in intermediate parts. Comrade Umz and gave me a good alternative, and I would do no harm if I say any more elegant than my formulas ORGANIZE "align" manner. Thanks.
PD. So was my document http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-bYhCyx8ElKI/Ut9XHmKiDAI/AAAAAAAACyQ/fES-xR-r9Jg/s1600/SH844.jpg with the numbers aligned with the right margin, I regret not having been able to express the thought at the beginning, my translation is a bit nascent sometimes.

Comment: @mathsalomon Your problem was perfectly clear to me. But : 1) align* should not produce any number. That's the difference between align* and align. 2) When I use align, equation numbers are exactly at the right margin. So there must be another problem, maybe another package that interferes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should let the `align` environment handle the numbering for you. Then the numbers will appear close to the right margin and the equations will be centered correctly.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{showframe}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}

The equation is
\begin{align}
4x &= 3x + 3.\\
\shortintertext{Then we have}
3x+3&\leq 4x <x+4.
\end{align}

\end{document}
```